# Clear content from "draw inside" - Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I have created a rounded rectangle and pasted picture inside of it by using "draw inside" tool.

Now I would like to clear inside drawing.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways -- the simplest is to double click on the photo, going into isolation mode, until you click down to the full picture that you pasted using draw inside. Then delete the image. If you're not familiar with isolation mode, check here: http://adobe.ly/1QbxkhZ

Answer (score 0):

Grab the **Direct Selection Tool** (the white arrow) -- click the photo.. hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

If it's a raster image, you can look at the **Links Panel**, highlight the image there and delete it using the Panel.

Comment: Hey @scott, how did you format that 'Delete' button to look like that?

Comment: @Alex you wrap the text in `<kbd>` tags. You can check out all the formatting options in the help from the post editor